# Using a VS Plugin to get a TFS changeset number?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I need to write a Visual Studio plugin to grab the TFS changeset number of the changeset the user has open so that it can be passed as an argument to another application that will be opened from the plugin. It would be even better if I could somehow add this plugin as a new list item under the "Actions" drop-down in Changeset Details.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I've never dealt with Visual Studio plugins before, so I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to install the Visual Studio SDK. Prior to VS 2015 the SDK was a separate download. In 2015 it is an optional feature and is called Visual Studio Extensibility Tools in Visual Studio Setup.

I followed this [tutorial](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/03/02/VisualStudioPackages.aspx) on Dotneteers to write a basic Visual Studio Package.

Comment: Alright, but I was more interested in knowing how I can retrieve the information I need from the changeset details screen and how to add the plugin to the context menu for a changeset.

Comment: The change-set details screen is part of Visual Studio. The Visual Studio SDK tools will allow you to add an item to the context menu. There are a couple steps to performing that task and it can be fiddly which is why I recommended the tutorial. The change-set number should be on the form.